# Litespeed connections for javascript files are not being kept alive, but are for jpeg and css files

Tags: http-headers, keep-alive, litespeed

Using Litespeed I have found that connections for javascript files are not being kept alive, but they are for jpeg and css files.

Using Firebug. Looking at the connection request headers for javascript files shows keep-alive
Looking at the connection response headers for javascript files shows close.

I have looked at the documentation for Litespeed and nowhere can I find a setting to disable keep-alive for javascript files.

Any and all suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

Litespeed have just issued a patch.  Connections for Javascript files are now kept-alive.